# Print finnish language text in php

Tags: php, localization, multilingual

I've written text in Finnish language in html and it worked fine. but when i'd placed all html in php then it didn't worked.

here is my code

```
<?php
        $html='<!DOCTYPE html>
        <!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
        <!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
        <!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="fi" xml:lang="fi" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <!--<![endif]-->

        <!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
        <head>
             <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <title>Login Page</title>
            <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
            <meta content="" name="description" />
            <meta content="" name="author" />

        </head>
            <!-- END HEAD -->

            <!-- BEGIN BODY -->
        <body >'; 
    $html=$html."<h4 style='font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;'><span lang='fi'>pitää pääosassa</span><h4>";

    $html=$html."</body></html>";

    echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: And "it didn't worked" means what, actually? Did you get an error? Nothing happened? Did you get the wrong result? Did the universe implode?

Comment: On a first glance I'd say you forgot the leading `<?php` which actually starts the interpretation of php...

Comment: Could also be the missing '>' in $html=$html."</body></html";

Comment: @arkascha unreadable text instead of non English characters

Comment: Ok, I interpret that "unreadable text instead of non English characters" such that you do not get the expected finnish character glyphs, but some replacements. That would mean that probably your text has been saved in a different character encoding, not UTF-8 as you claim in the document. Please check your editors settings.

Comment: @arkascha same html working fine when i remove php

Comment: Php might add additiinal headers to your http servers response. Take a look into your browsers development console and check the responses. Any difference?

Comment: Try adding the MIME header into the PHP `<?php header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8'); ...` or check the actual encoding of the file (if you open it in something like Notepad++ it's displayed in the status bar - bottom right)

Comment: @CD001 i placed it but no luck :(

Comment: Odd - I literally just copy/pasted your code from this page into Notepad++ saved it on a local webserver and ran it without issue; I'm getting **pitää pääosassa** on screen - as expected.

Comment: @CD001 i solved it by just putting all text in $html=utf8_encode($html); +1 for your effort. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by just adding all text in utf8_encode() function like that

```
<?php

$html="<h4 style='font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;'><span lang='fi'>pitää pääosassa</span><h4>";
$html=utf8_encode($html);
echo $html;

?>
```